# prisma graphql pass argument to a nested query

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server, prisma

I have a graphql query that pulls a Business by id , and then retrive all the reviews related to that business.

```
query Business($id: ID!) {
    business(id: $id) {
      _id
      name
      desc
      reviews {
        _id
        text
        createdAt
        published
}
}
```

the challenge I had is I would like to pull only the published reviews. I was able to acheive this by using a field resolver. however I am not too sure if it is the best way because the query already did the heavy work of pulling all the reviews and the reolver only filter the published ones.

```
const Business = {
  reviews: (parent, args, ctx, info) => parent.reviews.filter(rev => rev.published)
}
```

below is my resolver with prisma query :

```
  async business(parent, args, { prisma, request }, info) {
    let opArgs = {}
    opArgs.where = { _id: args.id }


    let post = null

    try {
      post = await prisma.query.business(opArgs, info)
      console.log(post)
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err.message)
    }

    return post
  },
```

my goal is to filter on the published review on the root. is there a better way to approach this.

any help please

Answer (score 0):

Can't you query reviews by id and published key? Just makes no sense to select all the reviews and after filter them.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more . Logically this is what ishould do but how?